# visudo changes not taken into account

Tags: sudo, root

I added three lines to my sudo configuration, using visudo.

```
User_Alias INSTALLERS = myusername

Cmnd_Alias INSTALL_CMDS = /bin/yum, /bin/make

INSTALLERS ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:NOEXEC: INSTALL_CMDS
```

After saving, if I run

```
sudo yum update
```

with myusername account, there are two problems:

1) I'm asked for my password

2) When I enter my password, I'm told "Sorry, user myusername is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/yum update' as root"

Any idea why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The command has to match exactly `/bin/yum` != `/usr/bin/yum/`

Comment: You're right. I though I had checked the path but I was wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: I always use `which` before adding a command to sudoers, lord knows I'm not immune to errors of that sort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the command you are authorizing in the sudoers file has the exact same path as found on the system. I often use `which`  to double check before adding it to the file, just to be sure.

Comment: You're right. My mistake was that I indeed used `which` but I didn't realized I ran `which` on my local system, while I was using visudo on the remote server. The path for yum on fedora is /bin/yum while it's /usr/bin/yum on Centos. Thanks!